# Content tab for table items

Tags: html, css, jquery-ui, tabs, accordion

I have  a accordion menu which contains table data inside. I need the tab structure for each td in the table, which means when I click on the each icon in the table a row of content should be opened just below that td with full width.

here is my accordion demo but accordion is not working here but u can see the table structure
http://jsfiddle.net/ut4fW/4/

Answer (score 0):

.accordion a
        {
            text-decoration: none;
            font: normal 16px "Trebuchet MS" , Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
            color: #222;
            padding: 0 0 0 8px;
            display: block;
            line-height: 30px;
            border-bottom: #FFF solid 1px;
            cursor: pointer;
            background: url(../images/arrow_normal.png) no-repeat 1%;
        }